# wicd: PEAP with TKIP/MSCHAPV2 not working

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, wicd

In `wicd`, I am using PEAP with TKIP/MSCHAPV2, and I get following error:

```
ERROR:dbus.connection:Exception in handler for D-Bus signal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 230,
in maybe_handle_message
    self._handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/wicd/gtk/gui.py", line 253, in handle_connection_results
    error(self.window, language[results], block=False)
KeyError: dbus.String(u'bad_pass')
```

I am sure, I am, using correct password.

Any suggestion how to troubleshoot this ?

I am leaving the "Path to CA cert" field empty.
Could this be causing the problem?

Connecting to other networks (using WPA) works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be related to `CA cert`, neither is this likely to be caused by DBUS.

Most likely, you are trying to authenticate using the wrong protocol (PEAP with TKIP/MSCHAPV2)

Similar problem is described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=126460). The solution is to use `PEAP with GTC` instead of `PEAP with TKIP/MSCHAPV2`.

Answer (score 1):

The default WICD doesn't have the PEAP with MSCHAPv2 template.

Try this:

```
 nano  /etc/wicd/encryption/templates/any_name
```

Create the folowing template:

```
 name = PEAP with TKIP/MSCHAPv2
 author = unknown
 version = 1
 require identity *Identity password *Password 
 -----
 ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
 network={
    ssid="$_ESSID"
    scan_ssid=$_SCAN
    proto=WPA
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=TKIP
    group=TKIP
    eap=PEAP
    identity="$_IDENTITY"
    password="$_PASSWORD"
    ca_cert="$_CA_CERT"
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
 }
```